# how to set cookie for IE9 for html file on hard drive

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a webpage that I run from my local hard drive. I am using localstorage to set the user preferences and that works with Chrome but I need to use this with IE9. What is the best way to set the user preferences for this, can I set a cookie with a local file?

Comment: When you say run from your local drive, are you talking about `http://localhost/` or is the file accessed via `file://`

Comment: Local storage has been supported in IE since version 8 if I'm not mistaken, so why use cookies ?

Comment: The file is named "myfile.html" and the file is located on my PC at  c:\myfile.html   when I open the file in Chrome the localstorage works fine, when I open the file with IE9 the localstorage does not work. I need a way to save the user preferences. I don't think cookies work for html files that are opened from a PC hard drive. I can't open this file from a server.